# Delete cookie bug in IE?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to delete some cookie which was set by javascript, it works well in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE, it deletes the cookie value in IE but not the file, so when I'm loading the page which uses cookie it loads some junk instead of nothing after delete.

I set the cookie like this

```
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 1);
            var c_value = escape(data.d) + "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "user" + "=" + data.d;
```

and delete it like this

```
document.cookie = 'user=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

where is my problem?

---

I also have the code in C# for ASP.Net to delete the cookie, but it doesn't work in none of web browsers, (it works for cookie which was set by C# but not with Javascript) where is the problem with this code as well?

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Cookies["user"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Cookies.Clear();
```

Comment: I think with the c# the problem is that you are Response.Cookies.Clear(); at the end so it is not sending the expired cookie to the browser. Try removing that line.

Comment: @Ben Robinson I didn't have that line first but it wasn't working and I put it there so it might!

Comment: There's no difference, really, between JavaScript cookies and cookies sent by the server. They're all cookies associated with your domain.

Comment: @ePezhman could you edit your question to show us the data IE leaves in the cookie after you deleted it? "it loads some junk instead of nothing after delete" - someone may have seen it or see it in future

Comment: I gave up and used some jQuery liberty which works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must send cookie to the response stream otherwise your modification will never be committed to the browser.

I usually use this code to logout:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
CurrentContext.Session.Abandon();
HttpCookie c = CurrentContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
if (c != null)
{
     c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
     CurrentContext.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating cookie Try to include domain name

Response.Cookies("abc").Domain = ".xyz.com"

and while deleting

```
Response.Cookies("uid").Value = Nothing

Response.Cookies("abc").Expires DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)

Response.Cookies("abc").Domain = ".xyz.com"
```

and Check your cookies using below Tools

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iecookies.html